# When using dotenv gem, the pages I wish to authenticate crash the app in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have added a scaffold to add bookings and post blogs on my application. However these need to be authenticated. I used the dotenv gem for this and now, although I have managed to push to heroku, the main functionality does not work. I have the config variables in the heroku dashboard. I'm fairly new to rails s. I'm struggling with how to get the app fully functioning on heroku. Thanks

My gem file looks like so:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.1'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

gem 'pg'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem "font-awesome-rails"


gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

end


group :development do

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'


  gem 'spring'
end
```

My Application.rb has this

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'dotenv' ; Dotenv.load ".env.local", ".env.#{Rails.env}"

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Owen
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

The logs output by heroku looks like this:

```
2016-08-09T13:01:00.950755+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2016-08-09T13:01:00.950755+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2016-08-09T13:01:00.950760+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-08-09T13:01:00.950758+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2016-08-09T13:01:00.950759+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
2016-08-09T13:01:00.904039+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-fbbd908cea354d615a36d08b266857a33539efedccec032961bf3f7e4b7fbd7e.css" host=mysterious-eyrie-34368.herokuapp.com request_id=607efaf0-bf7c-4b6e-a6aa-d5826431865d fwd="37.228.247.76" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-08-09T13:01:00.906216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-b1affcac82903b220e62f8a83f67d4523e5d7193c77560b624c4d295bcf53182.js" host=mysterious-eyrie-34368.herokuapp.com request_id=89e148bb-d39b-45b3-a2e0-dd4e67ebea45 fwd="37.228.247.76" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
```

This is when the dotenv-rails gem is in the development group

```
/app/config/application.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- dotenv (LoadError)
        from /app/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I suggest you use dotenv only in development. For production in heroku use heroku env variables. So put gem 'dotenv-rails', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.1' in  group :development

Comment: @loloso Which would I put it in? I just get an application error when I put it in either development group.

Comment: can you post the full error?

Comment: I get an application error.. Take a look [here](https://mysterious-eyrie-34368.herokuapp.com) . I have added the heroku rails console error to the original question.

Comment: can you chat because this is hard :)

Comment: Yes, how do you chat?

Comment: can you go to menu STackExchange and click chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120543/discussion-between-loloso-and-user2026178).

Comment: @lolosohave you gone to the chat window?